# Symfony: logout automatically in a very short period of time

Tags: symfony, authentication, lifetime

Whenever a user connect to the application after a very short period of time (like 2 or 3 minutes) he gets logged out from the application.
I thought it's the session's lifetime that being very short so I have increased it in the `config.yml` file like this:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 7200
```

But still the same problem.
The application works fine on locahost but I face this when it's running remotely!
Is there anything I should be aware of to fix this issue?

Comment: Where do you host it on production? Which setup do you have?

Comment: I host it at https://www.ovh.com, and what do you mean setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `session.cookie_lifetime` in the php.ini file of your remote server, I'm not sure but it may override the parameters in Symfony.

After you change it, don't forget to restart php so the change is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm not root so I can't touch the `php.ini` file